# Remove device history wireless hotspot

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, wireless, hotspot

I have been using Raspberry pi 3B as a wireless hotspot following this [How to use your Raspberry Pi as a wireless access point](https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/). I think there is a limit to a number of devices that can be connected to the pi. I think it remember a certain number of devices that get connected to it but not sure how many? Anybody have any ideas? And how do I clear the history so that I can connect new devices. Already connected devices have no problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The maximum number will be for the active connections. You should not need to clear a 'connection cache' or something like that. And yes, there is a limit. It will depend on the driver but you don't say what wifi device you're using so it's impossible to say any more about that.

Comment: The reason i say that i need to clear cache is that when i try to connect new devices, they won't connect to the network. So i want remove old devices to join my new device.

Comment: Did you check for any error messages on client and server side?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit. I am a novice. Thanks

Comment: Not really. You did not share your configuration (hardware, software, software configuration), so it's almost impossible to get more specific.

Comment: Please tell me what command to run so that i can post the output

Comment: Sorry, you don't seem to understand at all. For a start you need to post information about the hardware you use (Model Pi, wifi device, etc). Then how you configured your AP (and maybe a link to some tutorial) and then any error messages you get when you try to connect. We (at least me) need that information to say anything relevant. Please add the requested information to your question

Comment: I am using Raspberry pi 3 model B

Comment: Used the tutorial form the following link:

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/amp/

Comment: When ever i try to connect like any other wifi, the new device is stuck at connecting to the network doesn't even get to obtaining ip address

Comment: do "old" devices still connect correctly?

Comment: Yes old devices work fine but connecting the new device is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

To get a step forward I start this answer that we can improve step by step. Because lack of information I do some assumptions. You have made a stand alone access point without connections to any other devices by ethernet (eth0). Only other devices can connect but cannot go into the internet with the RasPi. You try to connect more than 20 devices to the access point. If you do not have modified the setup of the access point provided by the link then it is not possible that more than 20 devices can connect to the RasPi. The dhcp server `dnsmasq` is configured in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and set to:

```
interface=wlan0
  dhcp-range=192.168.0.11,192.168.0.30,255.255.255.0,24h
```

From 192.168.0.11 to 192.168.0.30 are 20 ip addresses reserved to give to clients. You can change this for example by modifying the second ip address to 192.168.0.110. Now you will have 100 ip addresses reserved to give to clients. The highest possible ip address for this subnet is 192.168.0.254. Don't decrease the first ip address because then it will conflict with the static ip address 192.168.0.10 of your access point.